# Get user ip using jquery and post to php page, ip returns empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ip

i am trying to get the users ip address using jquery and store that ip address in var, then send that variable to my php page to be inserted via SQL to my database.

```
     function rateMedia(mediaId, rate, numStar) {
    $('.box' + mediaId).html('<img src="design/loader-small.gif" alt=""
     />');
    var ip = 1; // i would like to store the ip address in a variable

    var data = {mediaId: mediaId, rate: rate, ip:ip}; // Create JSON
    which will be send via Ajax, this includes the variable for the ip

    $.ajax({ // JQuery Ajax
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/tuto-star-rating.php', // URL to the PHP file which will insert new value in the database
        data: data, // We send the data string
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 3000,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.box' + mediaId).html('<div style="font-size: small;
     color: green">Thank you for rating</div>'); // Return "Thank you
      for 
      rating"
            // We update the rating score and number of rates
            $('.resultMedia' + mediaId).html('<div style="font-size: 
 small; color: grey">Rating: ' + data.avg + '/' + numStar + ' (' + 
 data.nbrRate + ' votes)</div>');
 ..............................
```

**tuto-star-rating.php**

```
if($_POST) {
    $mediaId = $_POST['mediaId']; // Media ID
    $rate = $_POST['rate']; // Your rate
    $ip = $_POST['ip']; //i would simply like to get the ip address
    like this


    $host   = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'mov';
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mov;host=localhost', $username,
    $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   ...............................

    $query = $bdd->execute('INSERT INTO tc_tuto_rating (media, rate, user_ip) VALUES 
    ('.$mediaId.', '.$rate.','.$ip.')'); // insert the new rate
    }
    ..............................
```

I have tried excluding ip from jQuery entirely and getting the ip address in the php script below which usually works. but it doest work if the ip variable is not declared before the post in the jQuery, the ip column in my database is empty doing it this way. code below

```
    <?php  

    if($_POST) {
    $mediaId = $_POST['mediaId']; // Media ID
    $rate = $_POST['rate']; // Your rate
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];



    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {

        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {

        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    }

    return $ip;

     }


    $host   = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'mov';
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mov;host=localhost', $username,
    $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $get_cat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tc_tuto_rating WHERE media
     = :media AND user_ip = :user_ip");

    $get_cat->bindParam(":media", $mediaId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $get_cat->bindParam(":user_ip", $ip, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $get_cat->execute();

   ?>
```

i have used `var ip = 1;` to test it. The ip address is stored correctly as 1 in the database, how can i correctly get the correct ip address. i have seen similar questions and tried most of them which either didnt work or couldn't figure out how to merge the solution with my code.

Comment: i cant see any code where you are inserting the `ip` in the database, and yes getting the `ip address` in sever side is more better rather than getting in `js` then saving to `var` and then sending it via `post` and then getting it again.

Comment: i inserted the ip address in the $get_cat variable seen in the last section of the code where i used PDO for the SQL query

Comment: that is actually a `SELECT` query to which you are binding the params for if i am not wrong , not `INSERT` in database. additionally can you print and see the the raw query that is generated against it. also you shouldnt use `PDO::PARAM_INT` for the ip address

Comment: yes you're right, i have updated the code. thanks